# Setting dimension of signal in Simulink/MATLAB function from workspace

Tags: matlab, global-variables, global, simulink, dimensions

Suppose I have a Simulink block that contains something like:

```
function y  = myFnc(x, par)

y = zeros(1, par(1)) + x;
```

I declare `par` as a Parameter in the **model explorer** and read its value from the workspace.
Now, Simulink infers that `y` is a **variable-size signal** with all the pretty nasty limitations associated with it.

Is there any way to parametrize signals dimensions from the workspace, yet leaving the signals fixed-size somehow?

In C/C++ I'd just declare a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What works with some limitations is to create a class with properties that are const like:

```
    classdef DIMS
        properties (Constant)
            NR_SIGNALS          = 10
            LEN_SIG             = 32000 
            BLOCKS              = 2 * DIMS.NR_SIGNALS
        end
    end
```

... and use the constant properties (e.g. `DIMS.LEN_SIG`) as parameters wherever applicable.

The parametrization will be fixed at compile time of the model and even hard-coded in the generated code (if applicable).